# (Help checking) proof of norm being submultiplicative

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, solution-verification

I have a new matrix norm defined as the sum of the absolute values of the elements: for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ define:

$$\|A\| = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|\alpha_{i,j}| = \sum\left(\begin{matrix} |\alpha_{1,1}| & ... & |\alpha_{1,n}| \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ |\alpha_{m,1}| & ... & |\alpha_{m,n}| \end{matrix}\right)$$

I'm trying to prove this norm is submultiplicative, i.e. $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$. Here's what I have, if somebody wouldn't mind checking it:

\begin{aligned}
\|AB\| &= \left\| \begin{matrix} \tilde{a}_1^Tb_1 & ... & \tilde{a}_1^Tb_n \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \tilde{a}_m^Tb_1 & ... & \tilde{a}_m^Tb_n\end{matrix} \right\| \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n |\tilde{a}_i^T b_j|  & \text{def. of norm}\\
&\leq  \sum_{i = 1}^m \sum_{j = 1}^n \|\tilde{a}_i\|_2 \|b_j\|_2 & \text{Cauchy-Schwartz}\\
&= \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \|\tilde{a}_i\|_2 \right) \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n  \|b_j\|_2 \right) & \text{algebra} \\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \|\tilde{a}_i\|_1 \right) \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n  \|b_j\|_1 \right) & \|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1 \\
& = \|A\|\|B\| & \text{norm is defined as sum of absolute value of elements}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Why are you considering $\|AB\|^2$ instead of $\|AB\|$?

Comment: Lol good question. I started out that way thinking it would help...but right, don't need it at all.

Comment: $ \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \|\tilde{a}_i\|_2 \right) \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n  \|b_j\|_2 \right) 
\leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^m \|\tilde{a}_i\|_1 \right) \left( \sum_{j = 1}^n  \|b_j\|_1 \right)$ There is a issue with this step. The correct inequality is $||x||_1\leq ||x||_2$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n$.